# How can I create a DataFrame slice object piece by piece?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame, and I want to select certain rows and columns from it. I know how to do this using `loc`. However, I want to be able to specify each criteria individually, rather than in one go.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.IndexSlice

index = [np.array(['foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
         np.array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'])]
columns = ["A",  "B"]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 2), index=index, columns=columns)
print df
print df.loc[idx['foo', :], idx['A':'B']]

              A         B
foo a  0.676649 -1.638399
    b -0.417915  0.587260
qux a  0.294555 -0.573041
    b  1.592056  0.237868


              A         B
foo a -0.470195 -0.455713
    b  1.750171 -0.409216
```

**Requirement**

I want to be able to achieve the same result with something like the following bit of code, where I specify each criteria one by one. It's also important that I'm able to use a `slice_list` to allow dynamic behaviour [i.e. the syntax should work whether there are two, three or ten different criteria in the `slice_list`].

```
slice_1 = 'foo'
slice_2 = ':'
slice_list = [slice_1, slice_2]

column_slice = "'A':'B'"
print df.loc[idx[slice_list], idx[column_slice]]
```

Comment: Is slice_2 meant to slice on the second index (e.g., a, b) or the first index (foo, qux)?

Comment: Just the second one.

Comment: You can probably inspire from this, where eval is used for multiple conditions in a dataframe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699886/filtering-dataframes-in-pandas-use-a-list-of-conditions

Comment: How are you generating your slice lists? Dynamically or manually? I'd be happy to expand my answer and help you more.

Comment: @Jammeth_Q dynamically. What I would do is for any given data frame is to check how many levels there are, and then for each level I'd ask the user to define what slice of that level the user wants. If the user doesn't specify anything I will default to the first item for that level. At the end I need to create a pd.IndexSlice combining all the individual slices. That's why it needs to be dynamic.

Comment: Obviously you haven't found what you are looking for.  The general feel I get about what you're asking doesn't sound that difficult.  In fact, I thought @TedPetrou pretty well covered it.  My point is, if it hasn't been answered to your satisfaction, it isn't because its too difficult a question.  You might want to put some additional work in to explaining what you want.  Once you do that, send me a message and I'll take a look.

Comment: @piRSquared  thanks, but Michael's answer below works for me as it shows how I could pass a list of slices that I can build on my own to suit the DataFrame I'm selecting from. The key thing I was missing was that I'd need to use tuples with a 'dynamic' argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building up on [the answer by Ted Petrou](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42982020/6525140):

```
slices = [('foo', slice(None)), slice('A', 'B')]
print df.loc[tuple(idx[s] for s in slices)]

              A         B
foo a -0.465421 -0.591763
    b -0.854938  1.221204

slices = [('foo', slice(None)), 'A']
print df.loc[tuple(idx[s] for s in slices)]

foo  a   -0.465421
     b   -0.854938
Name: A, dtype: float64

slices = [('foo', slice(None))]
print df.loc[tuple(idx[s] for s in slices)]

              A         B
foo a -0.465421 -0.591763
    b -0.854938  1.221204
```

You have to use tuples when calling `__getitem__` (`loc[...]`) with a 'dynamic' argument.

You could also avoid building the `slice` objects by hand:

```
def to_selector(s):
    if isinstance(s, tuple) or isinstance(s, list):
        return tuple(map(to_selector, s))
    ps = [None if len(p) == 0 else p for p in s.split(':')]
    assert len(ps) > 0 and len(ps) <= 2
    if len(ps) == 1:
        assert ps[0] is not None
        return ps[0]
    return slice(*ps)

query = [('foo', ':'), 'A:B']
df.loc[tuple(idx[to_selector(s)] for s in query)]
```

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve this using the `slice` built-in function. You can't build slices with strings as ':' is a literal character and not a syntatical one.

```
slice_1 = 'foo'
slice_2 = slice(None)
column_slice = slice('A', 'B')
df.loc[idx[slice_1, slice_2], idx[column_slice]]
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I'd like to be able to use a list of slices, rather than specify each slice. Question updated!

Comment: Hi, any chance you know how to make this more dynamic with a slice list rather than naming individual slices?

Answer (score 4):

You might have to build your "slice lists" a little differently than you intended, but here's a relatively compact method using `df.merge()` and `df.ix[]`:

```
# Build a "query" dataframe
slice_df = pd.DataFrame(index=[['foo','qux','qux'],['a','a','b']])
# Explicitly name columns
column_slice = ['A','B']

slice_df.merge(df, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner').ix[:,column_slice]

Out[]: 
              A         B
foo a  0.442302 -0.949298
qux a  0.425645 -0.233174
    b -0.041416  0.229281
```

This method also requires you to be explicit about your second index and columns, unfortunately. But computers are great at making long tedious lists for you if you ask nicely.

**EDIT - Example of method to dynamically built a slice list that could be used like above.**

Here's a function that takes a dataframe and spits out a list that could then be used to create a "query" dataframe to slice the original by. It only works with dataframes with 1 or 2 indices. Let me know if that's an issue.

```
def make_df_slice_list(df):
    if df.index.nlevels == 1:
        slice_list = []
        # Only one level of index
        for dex in df.index.unique():
            if input("DF index: " + dex + " - Include? Y/N: ") == "Y":
                # Add to slice list
                slice_list.append(dex)
    if df.index.nlevels > 1:
        slice_list = [[] for _ in xrange(df.index.nlevels)]
        # Multi level
        for i in df.index.levels[0]:
            print "DF index:", i, "has subindexes:", [dex for dex in df.ix[i].index]
            sublist = input("Enter a the indexes you'd like as a list: ")
            # if no response, the first entry
            if len(sublist)==0:
                sublist = [df.ix[i].index[0]]
            # Add an entry to the first index list for each sub item passed
            [slice_list[0].append(i) for item in sublist]
            # Add each of the second index list items
            [slice_list[1].append(item) for item in sublist]
    return slice_list
```

I'm not advising this as a way to communicate with your user, just an example. When you use it you have to pass strings (e.g. `"Y"` and `"N"`) and lists of string (`["a","b"]`) and empty lists `[]` at prompts. Example:

```
In [115]: slice_list = make_df_slice_list(df)

DF index: foo has subindexes: ['a', 'b']
Enter a the indexes you'd like as a list: []
DF index: qux has subindexes: ['a', 'b']
Enter a the indexes you'd like as a list: ['a','b']

In [116]:slice_list
Out[116]: [['foo', 'qux', 'qux'], ['a', 'a', 'b']]

# Back to my original solution, but now passing the list:
slice_df = pd.DataFrame(index=slice_list)
column_slice = ['A','B']

slice_df.merge(df, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner').ix[:,column_slice]
Out[117]: 
              A         B
foo a -0.249547  0.056414
qux a  0.938710 -0.202213
    b  0.329136 -0.465999
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.IndexSlice

index = [np.array(['foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
         np.array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'])]
columns = ["A",  "B"]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 2), index=index, columns=columns)
print df

# 
la1 = lambda df: df.loc[idx['foo', :], idx['A':'B']]
la2 = lambda df: df.loc[idx['qux', :], idx['A':'B']]
laList = [la1, la2]

result = map(lambda la: la(df), laList)
print result[0]
print result[1]

              A         B
foo a  0.162138 -1.382822
    b -0.822986 -0.403766
qux a  0.191695 -1.125841
    b  0.669254 -0.704894
              A         B
foo a  0.162138 -1.382822
    b -0.822986 -0.403766
              A         B
qux a  0.191695 -1.125841
    b  0.669254 -0.704894
```

Comment: Nope, afraid not.

Answer (score 0):

Did you simply mean this?

```
df.loc[idx['foo',:], :].loc[idx[:,'a'], :]
```

In a slightly more general form, for example:

```
def multiindex_partial_row_slice(df, part_idx, criteria):
    slc = idx[tuple([slice(None) if i != part_idx else criteria 
                     for i in range(len(df.index.levels))])]
    return df.loc[slc, :]

multiindex_partial_row_slice(df, 1, slice('a','b'))
```

Similarly you can always narrow your current column set by appending `.loc[:, columns]` to your currently sliced view.